# Is exponential function in a C*-algebra injective on self-adjoint elements?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I asked this question in [stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993861/is-exponential-function-in-a-c-algebra-injective-on-self-adjoint-elements), but it flashed and disappeared:

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, the usual exponential function from $A$ into $A$. Is it true that if $x\ne y\in A$, $x^*=x$, $y^*=y$, then $\exp(x)\ne\exp(y)$?

Comment: Yes, because $x=\lim_{n\to\infty} n(e^{x/n}-1)$ and $e^{x/n}$ is the unique positive $n$th root of $e^x$.

Comment: In a unital $C^*$-algebra, It induces a bijection betweend self-adjoint element and positive inversible self adjoint element: its inverse is the logarithm.  ANd because these two functions are holomorphic one should even be able to say something similar for Banach algebra.